# Rails Paperclip plugin - Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

The [rails plugin paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master) supports validations at the model such as:

```
validates_attachment_size
```

The only problem is that using this validation seems to force the validation of an actual attachment, where sometimes there may not be one.

If I'm validating the following, what condition :if could I use to ignore the validation if there is not :document present? (meaning the user submitted the parent object without a document attached).

```
validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => 5.megabytes, :if => ???
```

The parent object is a :note, so in the note.rb file I have:

```
has_attached_file :document
```

RDocs: dev.thoughtbot.com/paperclip/

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in `:if => lambda { avatar.dirty? }` after the validation statement, assuming your attachment is named **avatar**. For example:

`validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 500.kilobytes, :if => lambda { avatar.dirty? }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `:allow_nil => true` option which will skip the validation if the attachment isn't present.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.  After adding:

validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => 5.megabytes, :allow_nil => true

Notes won't save to the database at all.  In my notes controller, I have an if statement saying if @note.save, do the good stuff, else redirect back to page with a flash error.

It redirects every time - @note.save won't fire correctly.  I have no other validations in notes that could be causing it to not save, since commenting out the paperclip validation makes everything work normal.

Comment: Logs don't detail anything specific to paperclip either (which is dissapointing).

Update: Check out the following: http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/issue/134

Answer (score 0):

Check for a file name.

```
validates_attachment_size :document, :less_than => 5.megabytes, :if => !self.document_file_name.nil?
```